# For loop is this returning 1 for count when >1 expected

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Below is my code:

```
function onlyYou(s){
  s = s.split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    var count = 0;
    if (s[i] = "r"||"a"||"w"){
      count = count + 1;
    };
  };
  alert(count);
};

onlyYou("you");
```

Running this code returns 1 and I'm not understanding why exactly, even if I put "y"||"o"||"u" it returns 1 instead of 3

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your `if` condition seems wrong. Not sure what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each iteration of the `for` loop, the variable `count` is set to equal `0` and then the `if` statement is evaluated, so count can only ever be equal to `0` or `1`, regardless of input.

You should declare count outside of the for loop like this:

```
function onlyYou(s){
  s = s.split("");
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    if (s[i] = "r"||"a"||"w"){
      count = count + 1;
    };
  };
  alert(count);
};

onlyYou("you");
```

Also, your condition `if (s[i] = "r"||"a"||"w")` is incorrect. Firstly, a single `=` indicates an assignment and not an evaluation, you should use `==` since this compares the two arguments, `s[i] = "r"` merely sets the variable `s[i]` to have the value `"r"`. Also, `|| "a"` is equivalent to `|| true` since you aren't comparing `"a"` to anything.

The condition should be:

```
if (s[i] == "r" || s[i] == "a" || s[i] == "w")
```

Comment: ... and fix the condition, because `if (s[i] = "r"||"a"||"w"){` is basically a `if(true){`

Answer (score 2):

You should take counter variable or `count` in this case out of loop. Also to check for specific letters you should use `if (s[i] == "r" || s[i] == "a" || s[i] == "w")`.

```js
function onlyYou(s) {
  s = s.split("");
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] == "r" || s[i] == "a" || s[i] == "w") {
      count = count + 1;
    };
  };
  alert(count);
};

onlyYou("you");
```

Answer (score 2):

1- You always get '1' because you initial the `count` variable within the loop so every time it gets again the value '0'.

```
function onlyYou(s){
s = s.split("");
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
var count = 0;
if (s[i] = "r"||"a"||"w"){
  count = count + 1;
};
};
alert(count);
};

onlyYou("you");
```

2- Why are you expecting to get `count=3` if your parameter is `"you"` and you compare it to `"raw"`?

`y` is not equal to `r`

`o` is not equal to `a`

`u` is not equal to `w`

3- Your if statement is wrong, instead of **checking** the values it actually assigns values into the `s` variable and changes it.

Change your condition like this:

```
function onlyYou(s){
s = s.split("");
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
var count = 0;
if (s[i] == "r"||s[i] == "a"|| s[i] == "w"){
  count = count + 1;
};
};
alert(count);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things amiss with this code:

1) Your `if` statement seems off. What it is doing is setting `s[i] = "r"` every time. I highly doubt this is the intended behavior.
2) You have a counter inside the loop which will get reset on every iteration.
3) The string you are passing in to test will seemingly not trigger the `if` condition anyway (assuming you want to check if the set {r, a, w} includes `s[i]`) - `"you"` would result in a count of 0.
4) Do not use semicolons after `if` blocks or `for` blocks.
5) More of a nitpick - there is no reason to split the string here.

```
function onlyYou(s) {
  for (var i = 0, count = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if ("raw".includes(s[i])) count ++;
  }
  alert(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the if condition evaluates to True always. This is because you wrote = instead of ==